# NuxtJS v2 check for typescript errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt application with config like this

`nuxt.config.js`

```
...
  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  ],
...
```

When I have a typescript error in code, I got an error during `yarn build`

```
ERROR in pages/index.vue:31:12
TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'String'.
    29 |   created() {
    30 |     const x: Array<String> = []
  > 31 |     x.push(12)
       |            ^^
    32 |     alert(x[0])
    33 |
    34 |     successToast(this, 'Yeah!')

 FATAL  Nuxt build error                                                                                                                                                                         23:25:44
```

Now, I run `yarn build` command on CI to verify that code has no typescript errors. But build command takes a lot of time, and I want to improve CI speed.

How can I check for typescript errors in the way `yarn build` do it without actually running build?

Comment: You could check for TS errors while coding thanks to a linter (baked-in into VScode). As of how to improve CI speed, you could do the checks on your local machine and bypass it on the CI. That way, you will have a faster workflow. One thing to note is that TS can be quite slow regarding the engine used behind and Webpack is not helping neither. That being said, I don't know TS so I really cannot help any further.